# 2 different divs start from the same point. Why isn't 2nd one below the other one?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place 2 different divs one after the another but they seem to be starting from the same point for some reason. Doesn't div divide that area of web page ?

```
<div class = "part1">
   <div id = "p1left"> something </div>
   <div id = "p1right"> something </div>
</div>

<div class = "part2">
   <div id = "p2left"> something </div>
   <div id = "p2right"> something </div>
</div>
```

while my css code is something like this :-

```
.part1, .part2 {
   position:relative;
}
#p1left, #p2left {
   float:left;
}
#p1right,#p2right {
   float:right;
}
```

Why is like 2nd div part of the first one? how do I put first before 2nd?

Comment: Can you send a picture i test it and its work Good

Comment: see this [https://jsfiddle.net/2xg9wjv6/](https://jsfiddle.net/2xg9wjv6/)

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS to

```
.part1, .part2 {
   position:relative;
   clear:both;
}
```

`clear:both` property removes the Left and right floating elements and ensures that the next div comes below the previous div.

[Working Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cj7acurn/)

Answer (score 1):

**Use this css**

```
.part1:after, .part2:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**OR add a new class something like .clearfix to both div and use below css:**

```
.clearfix:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use clear in css to make the div appear alone horizontally

```
clear:both;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
.part1, .part2 {
   float:left;
}
#p1left, #p2left {
   float:left;
   margin:5px;
}
#p1right,#p2right {
   float:left;
   margin:5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xre9j6k2/

Answer (score 0):

Please find below, the updated HTML and CSS

**HTML**

```
<div class="part1">
    <div id="p1left"> something 1</div>
    <div id="p1right"> something 2</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="part2">
    <div id="p2left"> something 3</div>
    <div id="p2right"> something 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.part1, .part2 {
   position:relative;
}
#p1left, #p2left {
   float:left;
}
#p1right,#p2right {
   float:right;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `position` attribute, you can do it like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <style type="text/css">
       div.divone{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: orange;
       }

        div.divtwo{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: yellow;
       }

      div.divone, div.divtwo{
       float:left;
      }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divone"></div>
  <div class="divtwo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you want to use with `position` attribute, you can do it by giving the position only to your second div like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

 <style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
 }
       div.divone{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: orange;
       }

        div.divtwo{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 300px;
       }



 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divone"></div>
  <div class="divtwo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```